# Make me a real-time reputation counter!

Tags: code-golf, stack-exchange-api

Recently, I have found my reputation changing time to time. I would like to know my reputation changing real-time.

---

## The job

Given an id of a user on PPCG (ex.64499), Print the user's reputation every 10 seconds. You may ignore the daily quota.

---

## Examples

```
64499
3808
40695
```

---

## Possible output format

```
12345
12,345
```

Comment: You really hate using the sandbox, right?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I do dislike it but I don't *hate* it, I just use it very hardly.

Comment: Do we have to worry about stack overflows?

Comment: @Dennis *stack overflows?*

Comment: Yes. If we call our function/program recursively, it will eventually stop working. Also, should we print the reputation *exactly* every 10 seconds or can we wait 10 seconds after printing the rep, not taking the time the query took into account?

Comment: @Dennis Worrying about stack overflows? no. The second question: the latter.

Comment: Yeah. Make a programming language where the function call stack is limited to size 5! :P [Continue discussion here if wanted](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)

Comment: For reputation 123456, can we print 123,456?

Comment: @Dennis Sure, if we can see the actual reputation.

Comment: Can I print `123,456 reputation` instead? If so, what additional information is allowed? I assume I couldn't simply display the entire web page...

Comment: If you edit your clarifications from the comments into the question and rule what exactly may be displayed in the output and if subsequent outputs are allowed to overwrite the previous one, I think this can be reopened.

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils + w3m, <s>90</s> <s>71</s> <s>69</s> 67 bytes

```bash
watch -tn10 w3m codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/$1\|grep -Pom1 ^[,-9]+
```

Takes the user ID as a command line argument and displays the reputation of the corresponding user (e.g., `135,249`) in the upper left corner of the terminal.

#### Alternate version, 57 bytes, invalid?

```bash
watch -tn10 w3m codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/$1\|sed 44!d
```

This displays `135,249 reputation` instead of `135,249`.

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/116592/make-me-a-real-time-reputation-counter#comment284770_116592) reply seems to assure you that if you can see the reputation it's valid, so I think that you can as well print `135,119 reputation`.

Comment: Also, this test run seems a little bit fake...

Comment: Hm, if I interpret it what way, I could just open the URL in any browser and let the user search for the reputation count.

Comment: Right, then you should ask OP if that's allowed. And I believe that the `,` is already interpreter *that way*, although it is in fact valid numeric representation.